# Intersection of two modules (and sub-modules) under tensors

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, tensor-products, intersection-theory

I have a (hopefully quick) question regarding an intersection of two tensor modules. Let $K$ be a field and $A, B$ finitely-generated modules over the Laurent series $K((X))$. Let $\tilde{A}$ be a (finitely-generated) $K[[X]]$-submodule of $A$, and similarly let $\tilde{B}$ be a (finitely-generated) $K[[X]]$-submodule of $B$. I am wondering if the following equality holds:

$$(A \otimes \tilde{B})\cap (\tilde{A} \otimes B) = \tilde{A} \otimes \tilde{B}.$$

I am aware of this statement holding in the case of algebras and vector spaces (e.g. Lemma 1.4.5 in Hopf Algbera: an introduction by Dascalescu et al.), but it is not exactly clear to me how the proofs in this context would generalise since the generators/basis for these tensors become unwieldly, so a similar approach does not seem intuitive to me. As sets, this statement seems more or less clear, but I am struggling to prove it for myself.

Thank you very much in advance for any help in this direction! M.